# Firebase Authentication with coroutines freezing UI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to do login feature for my app using Firebase Authentication, coroutines and MVVM pattern. The point is authentication only gives me callback if it is successful, otherwise it freeze whole app and I don't know why. I am very new to android programming and I rely on projects from the internet and my code might be messy. Here is my code:

Firebase repository:

```
class UserRepositoryImpl : UserRepository {

    private val authentication: FirebaseAuth by lazy {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    override suspend fun firebaseLoginUser(email: String, password: String): Result<FirebaseUser?> {
        try{
            return when(val authResult =  authentication.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await())
            {
                is Result.Success<*> -> {
                    val firebaseUser = authentication.currentUser
                    Result.Success(firebaseUser)
                }
                is Result.Error -> {
                    Result.Error(authResult.exception)
                }
                is Result.Canceled ->{
                    Result.Canceled(authResult.exception)
                }
                else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
            }
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            return Result.Error(e)

        }
    }
```

Class for authentication callback:

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
    data class Canceled(val exception: Exception?) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Custom Task.await() method:

```
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): Result<T>
{
    if (isComplete)
    {
        val e = exception
        return if (e == null)
        {
            if (isCanceled){
                Result.Canceled(CancellationException("Task $this was cancelled"))}
            else {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                Result.Success(result as T)}
        }
        else {
            Result.Error(e) }
    }

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        addOnCompleteListener {
            val e = exception
            if (e == null)
            {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                if (isCanceled) {
                    cont.cancel() }
                else {
                    cont.resume(Result.Success(result as T)) }
            }
            else {
                cont.resumeWithException(e) }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class AuthenticationViewModel(
        private val repository: UserRepositoryImpl
) : ViewModel() {

//Databinding values
var email: String? = null
     var password: String? = null

private val _toastMessage = MutableLiveData<Any?>()
     val toastMessage: LiveData<Any?>
          get() = _toastMessage

fun login() {
          if (email.isNullOrEmpty() || password.isNullOrEmpty()) {
               _toastMessage.value = R.string.login_noCredentials
               return
          }
          else{
               viewModelScope.launch {
                    when (val result = repository.firebaseLoginUser(email!!, password!!)) {
                         is Result.Success -> {
                                   // app.startHomeActivity()
                              }
                         }
                         is Result.Error -> {
                              _toastMessage.value = result.exception.message
                         }
                         is Result.Canceled -> {
                              _toastMessage.value = R.string.login_canceled
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
     }
```

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html

Comment: I was following sample project from the internet and this is how it was done, I have not tried basic coroutine approach actually, will try out

Comment: Your custom implementation seems fine, though. One issue i see with the code is that you're supposed to make the application move on after login explicitly, through `startHomeActivity()`, but you just show a toast when login fails. So the GUI isn't literally "frozen", just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Found an issue, it was because I set toastMessage to null and then observing it in login fragment, somehow it was freezing my UI, removing it fixed it all.